# GCP - what are mysql-access instances?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I have my application deployed to AppEngine Standard and connects to Cloud SQL via public IP. I was looking at VM instances dashboard and found a set of instances with the following naming pattern and these are alerting for high cpu utilization.

aet-uswest1-mysql--access-

The description says "Anthos/GKE and Dataproc VMs are Google-managed and include built-in agents.". These are all e2-micro instances and I could not change the instance type. At first I thought these are the underlying AppEngine instances, but the AppEngine instances I use for F4 class, I think these are something else.

What are these instances and how are they used?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding that AppEngine service was connected to Mysql via public network is incorrect. I found that these instances are related to VPC connector used by AppEngine standard to access MySQL service.